# array_multisort() isn't sorting by column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am using this line to sort my two dimensional array in ascending order based on name field.

```
array_multisort($contact[0]['name'], SORT_DESC, $contact[0]['image'], $contact[0]['url'], $contact[0]['catimg'], $contact[0]['count']);
```

But some times it's not sorting correctly.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what `not sorting correctly.` mean ?

Comment: what is the structure of array?

Comment: btw, you pass `SORT_DESC` and ask for  ascending order

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow because there is no [mcve]. This page should be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make columns of data if you want to use `array_multisort` to work, in outline it will look like this:

```
$names = array();
$images = array();
$urls = array();
// ... add more as needed
// make rows of data for sorting
foreach ($contact as $contact_row) {
    $names[]  = $contact_row['name'];
    $images[] = $contact_row['image'];
    $urls[]   = $contact_row['url'];
    // ... add more as needed
}
array_multisort($names, SORT_DESC, $images, $urls, $contact); // the last one is the array you want to sort

var_export($contact); // at this point this should be ordered
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, thats arguments passed to function are not arrays.

Try use usort:

```
usort($contact, function($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```